# Animate Text with javascript / Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

i want to animate multi words like this site : http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/
**Available, .com** ---->  [image]

HERE'S MY FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/to61vaL6/

can anyone tell me what's the best approach to create something like this ? and with this fiddle i can animate one word , how can i animate more than that ?

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.initComVal = '.com';
    $scope.comval = '';
    function changeText (){
        if($scope.comval.length === $scope.initComVal.length)
            $scope.comval = '';
        else
        {
            $scope.comval = $scope.initComVal.substring(0, $scope.comval.length+1);
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log($scope.comval);
        }
    }

    setInterval(changeText,100);
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep the words you wish to display in an array, and then iterate through them as your words display.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var values = ['.com', 'available'];
    var index = 0;
    $scope.comval = '';
    function changeText (){
        if(values[index].length == $scope.comval.length) {
            $scope.comval = '';
            index++;
            if (index >= values.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.comval = values[index].substring(0, $scope.comval.length+1);
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log($scope.comval);
        }
    }

    setInterval(changeText,100);
});
```

Also, take care not to abuse angular's scope.  If you're just starting out with using AngularJS, I recommend reading up on [johnpapa's angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and answer, how can i add delay between call function not run function ? setInterval is for run fuction not for call

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval#repeating-with-known-delay